# How do I predict ball movement, after collision, in game of pool?

Tags: unity, c#, physics

I'm trying to draw lines that predict the movement after collision between two balls, in a game of pool. How do I do that?

I heard it can be done via raycasts, but how do I draw a line?

Comment: wich engine are you using? In Unity , Physics.SphereCast would be a better choice for calculating pool balls touch point.

Comment: Im sorry, I forgor to mention that Im using Unity + C#.